# Two SQL Server databases share the same MDF and LDF files but have different data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, datafile

I have a strange circumstance where I have a production database and a restored copy as another database on the same SQL Server instance, and both of them are using the same MDF and LDF files (i.e. they have the same "Logical" files in SQL Server Management Studio).  From what I've found while researching this, [it is possible](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71228/two-sql-server-databases-setup-with-same-mdf-and-ldf-files), but all indications are that they would both be pointing to the same *data*, a reasonable assumption.

However, in my case, both databases actually contain *different data*.  If I run a select statement on two tables with the same name, one in each database, they return different data.  I've double, triple, and quadruple verified this.  How is this possible?  None of the MS docs or anything I've found have talked about two DBs sharing the same MDF files but having different data.

There are no NDF files involved, and there is one file group in each DB with only one file in each file group.

Comment: Run this query and show us the output (add a WHERE clause for the 2 databases so you don't have to post everything): select database_id, name, physical_name from master.sys.master_files

Comment: Ahh yes, they're pointing at different files.  I'm looking at the properties of each DB in SSMS, but they show them as the same (logical) files.  I guess you can't see the "actual" files in SSMS?

Comment: Logical File can be same, physical files are always different.

Comment: For comparison, you can run a similar query on each database: `SELECT name, physical_name FROM sys.database_files`. I've found a few cases (like if a database is READONLY) where the file might get moved and is out of date at the db level, but correct in MASTER.

Comment: @Kin -- do you know where I can see physical files using SSMS?  Or is querying like this the only way?

Comment: Of course you can see the "actual" files in SSMS. You just did, when you ran the query Tara gave you. More to the point: in SSMS, right-click on your database; select "Properties"; go to the "File" tab; and scroll the resulting screen to the right. The logical name is the first column in the display; the path and physical file name are the last two columns, and you have to scroll over to see them.

Comment: Haha, man I feel like an idiot now.  It was just a scrollbar issue.  Oops!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible to have two databases point to the same database files, except in the weird Autoclose case that you linked to, which no one should be using that setting anyway.

Run the below query to view what physical files the databases are pointing to:

```
SELECT database_id, name, physical_name 
FROM master.sys.master_files
```

With that information, you should be able to see that the databases are in fact not pointing to the same database files.

You also can see this information in the SSMS GUI. Right click on the database, go to properties and then to Files. Now SCROLL to the right as the physical files aren't visible yet. The combination of Path and File Name will be unique.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Even though I'm just an idiot :)

Comment: Nah, you just didn't know where to look. Now you do.